# Does upgrading APNs to Authentication token from certificate invalidate existing deviceToken?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm planning to migrate the APNs to the Authentication tokens system from the old (certificate based), but I don't want to invalidate the existing valid tokens. Does anybody have any experience with this? Will the existing token still works after migration?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token is generated on the device that will receive the notification and is based on your bundle ID and the device. It is not dependent on the credentials that your server uses to connect to the APNS service (The iOS device has no information on this).

As a result you can change the way you connect and authenticate without any impact to existing tokens. It is no different to using a new certificate when the old one expired with the old system.

Comment: Sounds good. Any cons of using the Auth token vs certificate?

Comment: No, the certificate is the older mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

Token is device specific and if you create an Auth token (which is new way of using push notifications as they have no expiry date), It would have no effect on device token. I guess the proper question here would have been whether the notifications using the old APNS certificates would still be working or not(considering it has been set up on the server as well) even in that case the answer would be Yes. As long as you do not revoke the certificates it would still be working

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this. The old APNs certificate still works even after generating Auth token. Thanks!